# Download Image and Display in Dialog

Tags: android, dialog, onclicklistener, universal-image-loader, buttonclick

I'm trying to load an image in a dialog via "Lazy Image Loader" to an imageview. I've included two code snippets to show the way I'm calling it.

---

----EDIT-----

Now Using universal image loader 1.8.6

```
Log.i(Utils.TAG, "Show Photo");
ImageLoader imgLoader = new ImageLoader(a);
imgLoader.DisplayImage(strUrl, image);
```

this is how i'm calling it since @TalhaQ way didn't work. Said it did not accept those number of paramaters

---

---- ORIGINAL---
Log cat show a valid url and image when i go to that url. Any ideas?

Utils.java

```
public Dialog openFeed(final Activity a, final long id) {

    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(a);
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.dialog_animation;
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.feed_item);


    //Set the Title & Descr to the Item Selected
    TextView title = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.txtItemTitle);
    title.setText(strTitle);

    TextView descr = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.txtItemDescription);
    descr.setText(strDescr);

    ImageView image = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.imgFeedImage);


    Log.i(TAG, "strUrl: " + a.getResources().getString(R.string.photoURL) + strUrl);

    ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader(a);
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(a.getResources().getString(R.string.photoURL) + strUrl, image);

    Button CommentButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonComment);

    // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
    CommentButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();

            final AlertDialog addComment = Utils.openComments(a, id);
            addComment.show();
        }
    });
```

XML:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgFeedImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtItemDescription"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/txtItemDescription"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtItemDescription"
    android:contentDescription="@string/itemicon"
    android:src="@drawable/gplus"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:maxHeight="200dp"
    android:visibility="invisible" />
```

Comment: could you post your log cat errors ?

Comment: There is not a logcat error. It just doesn't download and show the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am also using the same Lazy Image Loader.I think you are not passing the context correctly.

```
   int loader = R.drawable.loader;//Old image in the imageview
   ImageLoader imgLoader = new ImageLoader(ctx); // ctx is the context
   imgLoader.DisplayImage(image_url, loader, image);//image is the imageview,image_url is the url to image
```

Check out my output.If you still needs any help i am attaching my sample.Download it.Check out the [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/n85xaiipqqacadg/SectionList.rar)

[image]

Comment: The method DisplayImage(String, ImageView) in the type ImageLoader is not applicable for the arguments (String, int, ImageView)

Comment: Can you please tell me which Lazy image loader are you using.Then i will create a sample for you.

Comment: tell me which your using and I'll move to it

Comment: I am using this..https://www.opendrive.com/files?NF8yMjk1Nzg5OV80d2tkbw  ...password: android

Comment: Sorry it took so long to get back to you... I've got a couple errors. 1) in the listview the first image does now show at first until you scroll down and back up. The image does not show up at all in the dialog and I'm guessing its probably the same issue but i cannot scroll.

Comment: If i need to post the activity and the adapter along with the dialogs i can... but its alot of code if you don't mind

Comment: Nevermind, I was able to fix it with the animateFirstListener in your example! Your a life saver.

Comment: Thanks..Keep coding :)

Comment: Can you take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22075767/universal-image-loader-and-only-showing-half-the-image

Answer (score 0):

When you load image in dialog than the below scenario occurred in image downloaded therefore you should handle ClassCastException inside the image loader below code will help you . That exception not occurs if imageview is inside list which load in fragment or activity or imageview inside activity

```
Activity a= (Activity)(photoToLoad.imageView.getContext());
```

You can't assume a Context can be casted to an Activity. Hence the exception: You're attempting to cast a Context that is in fact a ContextThemeWrapper to an Activity.

You can replace

```
Activity a= (Activity)(photoToLoad.imageView.getContext());
a.runOnUiThread(bd);
```

with e.g.

```
photoToLoad.imageView.post(bd);
```

to post a Runnable to UI thread message queue, similar to Activity runOnUiThread()